# Linq To SQL: left join and vb.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 r.* FROM dbo.Request r
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Process p
  ON r.IdReq = p.IdReq
WHERE IdProcess Is NULL
ORDER BY r.ReqDate ASC
```

I want write it in a vb.net procedure, using Linq To SQL syntax:

```
Private Function getOldestRequest() As Request
    Dim dc As ProcessDataContext = new ProcessDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("...").ConnectionString);

    Dim pr = From r In dc.Request
             From p In dc.Process.Where(Function(v) v.IdReq = r.IdReq And v.idProcess Is Nothing)
             Select New {Request = r}

    Return pr
End Function
```

This is what I wrote, but I get error, on the `Return` line.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ statements return IEnumerable objects, and your method is returning a single Request object. In your case looks like you only need to return the first result of the LINQ statement.

Something like:

```
    Dim pr = (From r In dc.Request
         From p In dc.Process.Where(Function(v) v.IdReq = r.IdReq And v.idProcess Is Nothing)
         Select New {Request = r}).FirstOfDefault
    Return pr
```

Comment: Is operator does not accept operand of type Integer. IdProcess is Integer

Answer (score 0):

Change your Select to

```
Select r
```

And your return to

```
Return pr.OrderBy(Function(v) v.RecDate).FirstOrDefault
```